# Typescript: How to find the correct types for event variables

Tags: typescript

I am using Typescript for the first time to convert an existing JS project. I have experience with C# so thought I would be OK with typing everything!

However, I'm having problems in places. For example, I have a CustomEvent handler:

```
document.addEventListener('beforeDrop', ((e: CustomEvent) => {
  if (testDrop(e.detail.from, e.detail.to) === false) {
    // stop the item being dropped by the library
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}) as EventListener);
```

and `testDrop` I have tried is

```
export function testDrop(from: Object,to: Object) {
  const toRow = Number(to.dataset.keepRow) ;
  const toCol = Number(to.dataset.keepCol) ;
  const type = from.dataset.type;
  ....
  ....
```

but of course `Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'Object'.`
So how do I find the correct type for a `customeevent.detail.from.dataset` , for example?

I note that the scaffolding for my project (VSCode / VueJS) has included a file `env.d.ts` which may be relevant but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: "I am using Typescript for the first time to convert an existing JS project. I have experience with C# so thought I would be OK with typing everything!" Everything about this is false. C# and TS are nothing alike. For example, everything about their type systems is completely different and incompatible. You need to learn JS in order to use TS effectively.

Comment: ?? Of course TS and C# are different. But they are both strongly typed, unlike JS. So, my meaning was, I should find the conversion easier than somebody who has no experience of a typed language.

Comment: And you won't find it so because the type systems are radically different.

Comment: And you won't find the conversion easier because the type systems are radically different. C# is _nominally_ typed with a fully reified system that requires a runtime that understands and supports that. TypeScript is _structurally typed with a fully erased type system that has no runtime manifestation whatsoever and its entirety designed to statically model the types of JavaScript code and which exists solely for the purpose of providing tooling support for developers. Correlating superficially similar constructs like `interface` as if they are analogous will lead to confusion and bad code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my `dataset` is a `DOMStringMap`.
So now I have

```
document.addEventListener('beforeDrop', ((e: CustomEvent) => {
  const fromData:DOMStringMap = e.detail.from.dataset;
  const toData:  DOMStringMap = e.detail.to.dataset;
  if (testDrop(fromData, toData) === false) {
  // stop the item being dropped by the library
     e.preventDefault();
  }
}) as EventListener);
```

and

```
export function testDrop(from: DOMStringMap,to: DOMStringMap) {
  const toRow = Number(to.keepRow) ;
  const toCol = Number(to.keepCol) ;
  const type = from.type;
  if (type===undefined) {
    throw 'trying to drop an undefined track type'
  }
  ....
  ....
}
```

and I don't need to create my own interface or type for that.

What I should do now is modify the creation of the event.

```
addEvent(name:string,fromEl:HTMLElement, toEl:HTMLElement | null) {
    const event = new CustomEvent(name, { cancelable: true, detail: {from:fromEl, to:toEl}});
    return document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

`detail` has type `any` but I could create a type

```
type CustomEventDetail = {
  from: HMTLElement,
  to:   HMTLElement
}
```

but the event creation is in a library module, so I would need to export the new type from the libary - after only 48 with TS I'm not ready for that stage yet!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Object type is just about as good as using the type 'any' which is really bad practice. You will have to make a type or interface for the dataset

```
interface Dataset {
  keepRow: number;
  keepCol: number;
  type: string;
}
```

and whatever other props are on that dataset. Then in your testDrop function you can use

```
export function testDrop(from: Dataset, to: Dataset) {
```

Comment: Thanks. OK so far (i.e. the transpiler is OK with that), But I assume I need to put this inerface into a declaration file so that the caller of `testDrop` also has access to it, to check that parameters match?